# Unknown string in Terminal

Tags: android, macos, cordova, terminal, reset

What does this mean, "android_358920041107720" and how do I get rid of this string when starting my Terminal?

I believe it came from me downloading PhoneGap/Cordova, but not entirely sure.

Any help or explanation of what I'm looking at would be greatly helpful!

Thanks.

Link to the image: http://cl.ly/image/321r1O003n13

Comment: It can be helpful to give information about the OS used and what kind of terminal/shell is this (cmd prompt,bash,...)

Answer (score 0):

That is an android host name identifier when requesting DHCP lease on the IP address... see this for example, that occurs on my network.

> dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.x.x to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   (android-***acc87f3d476374c1***) via eth0

It could also be used to signify the Android's host name from within the `adb shell`, depending on the flavour of the ROM and version used.